# Zeppelin - Unable to instantiate SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to get Zeppelin to work. But when I run a notebook twice, the second time it fails due to `Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient`. (full log at the end of the post)

It seems to be due to the fact that the lock in the metastore doesn't get removed. It is also advised to use for example Postgres instead of Hive as it allows multiple users to run jobs in Zeppelin.

I made a postgres DB and a `hive-site.xml` pointing to this DB. I added this file into the config folder of Zeppelin but also into the config folder of Spark. Also in the jdbc interpreter of Zeppelin I added similar parameters than the ones in the `hive-site.xml`.

The problems persists though.

**Error log:** http://pastebin.com/Jqf9cdtU

**hive-site.xml:** http://pastebin.com/RZdXHPX4

Answer (score 2):

Try using Thrift server architecture in the Spark setup instead of working on a single instance JVM of Hive where you cannot generate multiple of sessions.

There are mainly three types of connection to Hive:

**Single JVM**  - Metastore stored locally in the warehouse which doesn't allow multiple sessions

**Mutiple JVM** - where each worker behaves as a metastore

**Thrift Server Architecture** - Multiple Users can access the SQL engine and parallelism can be achieved

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how to get the Thrift architecture going? Atm I changed the Thrift property in my hive-site.xml to localhost:9083 but it gives a connection issue.

Comment: Because at the moment im getting a `Caused by: MetaException(message:Could not connect to meta store using any of the URIs provided. Most recent failure: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)` so I assume there is something going wrong with my Thrift?

Comment: Connection refused occurs when the ports are not open. Yes it looks like there is some issue with your Thrift server. Re-install the Thrift with latest build and connect with postgresDB updated connector.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database
```

By default, spark use derby as the metadata store which can only serve one user. It seems you start multiple spark interpreter, that's why you see the above error message. So here's the 2 solutions for you

1. Disable hive in spark interpreter via setting zeppelin.spark.useHiveContext to false if you don't need hive.
2. Set up hive metadata store which support multiple users. Refer this https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cdh_ig_hive_metastore_configure.html

Comment: Setting zeppelin.spark.useHiveContext to false did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Stop Zeppelin. Go to your `bin` folder in Apache Zeppelin and try deleting `metastore_db`

```sh
sudo rm -r metastore_db/
```

Start Zeppelin again and try now.